# Strange thing happens when i restore my model in Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning

I just want to load my previously saved model and train it further, my code works just fine until the restoring step,things become strange when i use ‘sess.run’. The program end immediately without executing ‘sess.run’.

But, when i removed my AdamOptimizer op, ‘sess,run’ came back to work

Why?

Here is the code:

```
ckpt_state = tf.train.get_checkpoint_state(last_checkpoint_path)
if not ckpt_state or not ckpt_state.model_checkpoint_path:
    print('No check point files are found!')
    return


ckpt_files = ckpt_state.all_model_checkpoint_paths
num_ckpt = len(ckpt_files)

if num_ckpt < 1:
    print('No check point files are found!')
    return

low_res_holder = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[BATCH_SIZE, INPUT_SIZE, INPUT_SIZE, NUM_CHENNELS])
high_res_holder = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[BATCH_SIZE, LABEL_SIZE, LABEL_SIZE, NUM_CHENNELS])

keep_prob = tf.placeholder(tf.float32)
is_training = tf.placeholder("bool", shape=[])

global_step = tf.Variable(0, trainable=False, name='global_step')

inferences = models.creat_Dense_Modelpatches(low_res_holder, 13, is_training, keep_prob)
training_loss = models.loss(inferences, high_res_holder, name='training_loss')

low_res_batches, high_res_batches = batch_queue_for_testing(TESTING_DATA_PATH)

learning_rate = tf.train.inverse_time_decay(0.001, global_step, 10000, 2)

train_step = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate).minimize(training_loss, global_step=global_step)

config = tf.ConfigProto()
config.gpu_options.allow_growth = True

sess = tf.Session(config=config)
sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
tf.train.start_queue_runners(sess=sess)

saver = tf.train.Saver(tf.global_variables())

ckpt_file = ckpt_files[-1]

saver.restore(sess, ckpt_file)

low_res_images, high_res_images = sess.run([low_res_batches, high_res_batches])

print("thie code has ran this line...")
```

When i ran this codes with

```
train_step = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate).minimize(training_loss, global_step=global_step)
```

The output would be

```
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:975] Creating TensorFlow device (/gpu:0) -> (device: 0, name: GeForce GTX 1080, pci bus id: 0000:05:00.0)
mt@sj408:~/JP/DR/DR$
```

But when train_step op is removed the output would be like this:

```
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:975] Creating TensorFlow device (/gpu:0) -> (device: 0, name: GeForce GTX 1080, pci bus id: 0000:05:00.0)
thie code has ran this line...
mt@sj408:~/JP/DR/DR$
```

Answer (score 0):

You may need to join all the threads you used for your asynchronous execution. Here's an example snippet from (https://www.tensorflow.org/programmers_guide/reading_data)

```
with tf.Session() as sess:
  # Start populating the filename queue.
  coord = tf.train.Coordinator()
  threads = tf.train.start_queue_runners(coord=coord)

  for i in range(1200):
    # Retrieve a single instance:
    example, label = sess.run([features, col5])

  coord.request_stop()    # <==== You are missing this
  coord.join(threads)     # <==== And this
```

If this doesn't fix your issue, it would be helpful to provide a minimal working example that I can debug locally.